# Zabbix Notifications on Event Update (ACK) not working

Tags: zabbix

### The Problem

We have a powerful legacy Zabbix 4.0 (ex LTS) in production that should send specific notifications when an Event is *Updated* by an operator (for example, after an "ACK"). So, an auditor can receive verbose updates, for extra auditing on the operations dep.

But, "Update" Actions are never fired.

We limited the problem to these Symptoms:

- Problems are correctly generated and related email notifications work
- but, updating it (ACK, comment...) does *not* generate additional notifications
- the Action log never mentions that stuff, no errors in logs. Like "totally ignored actions"
- even if we have an (apparently) correct related Action to be fired after an "Update operation"
- even if our users have the related Media Type enabled (working for other stuff)

### Configuration

Following the documentation, we created a new Action, enabled.

To help in troubleshooting, we have also even set a dummy condition that is always true.

[image: Zabbix 4.0 screenshot, menu: Actions > create new]

As you know, the interface clearly states that at least one operation, one recovery operation or one update operation should be specified; so, we specified indeed just our "Update operations".

[image: Zabbix 4.0 screenshot, menu: Action > Update operations]

So, when somebody clicks ACK, or comment an Event, Zabbix should send an email to "Valerio". So we configured the related Media Type for that User:

[image: Zabbix 4.0 specific user email media type popup opened]

But, this does not work (I mean, again, the very same Media Type on the very same User works for different Actions, but not this one - no interesting server logs - no action logs). When the user is testing the feature, and leaves a comment, that user does not receive any notification even if the Action seems quite hardcoded to always contact that specific user "Valerio".

Thanks for any Troubleshooting tip in comments to enrich this question, and for any answer.

As complementary context, we are interested in the next step, that is, do not "just" send an email to "Valerio" when an operator ACKs, but execute a [custom Zabbix alert script](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/en/manual/config/notifications/media/script) assigned to somebody. So an external system can receive every Event update (ACK, Operator messages, etc.) almost in real-time and expose these. So we could easily integrate the update history of Zabbix to, but not limiting to, Phabricator/Phorge, IRC, and other interesting platforms, since you know how Bash can be a powerful glue for a lot of things. But, update Actions are not fired in our tests.

---

All screenshots here are shared by me but available with the following credits:

© [Zabbix LLC.](https://www.zabbix.com/) under [GNU General Public License v2](https://www.zabbix.com/license)

Answer (score 1):

You have done everything correctly, but note this corner-case:

> *The person who updates a problem does not receive notification about their own update.*
>
> ― https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.0/en/manual/config/notifications/action/acknowledgment_operations

You correctly configured an Action to notify updates to your specific user (that may have an email, or a custom script indeed, etc.). *But* you are probably performing tests from the very-same Zabbix user. This kind of self-tests can never work in Zabbix.

### Solution

Be sure to have a *dedicated user* for this kind of things (running custom scripts to handle notifications), and *another* user performing the comments / ACK / etc.

With at least two users you will finally get Action logs, etc. and you can proceed with your troubleshooting.

### Additional Troubleshooting

Look at the Action Logs (`/auditacts.php` in Zabbix Frontend) and server logs.